# <p:dataTable ajax issues after pagination

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm using primefaces 3.4 (old one I know, but can't upgrade atm) , I know that in primefaces 5 my issue is resolved (but I really can't upgrade atm)

When using lazy / non lazy loading datatable with pagination I encounter the following issues,

1) ajax inputs (inside `<p:dataTable`) are not firing after pagination (page > 1)

2) element states (`<h:selectBooleanCheckbox`) are not reflected upon form submitting (even though I do see them being sent to server)

Any idea whats causing this misbehavior of primefaces / how to track it down / how can it be fixed in the 3.4 version?

My guess it has something to do with the following BalusC answer [commandLink/commandButton/ajax backing bean action/listener method not invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2120183/617373) (N#4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I solved it with the following trick:

```
<p:ajax event="page" listener="#{myBean.detectPageEvent}" oncomplete="updateModel()"></p:ajax>
```

where the content of the bean `detectPageEvent` method looks like this:

```
public void detectPageEvent(PageEvent ev) {
    //SET page number
    ((LazyDeviceDataModel) lazyModel).setPageNumber(ev.getPage());
}
```

where the content of the js updateModel function is:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#table-refresh-after-page').click();
}, 10);
```

and in the xhtml page I have added the following

```
<h:commandButton id="table-refresh-after-page"
    styleClass="hide" action="#{myBean.updatePageNumber}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

where the `updatePageNumber` method looks like this

```
public void updatePageNumber() {
    DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot()
            .findComponent("my-form:my-table");
    dataTable.setFirst(((LazyDeviceDataModel) lazyModel).getPageNumber() * 10);
}
```

---

As I said before : My guess it has something to do with the following BalusC answer [commandLink/commandButton/ajax backing bean action/listener method not invoked][1] (N#4)